# compare sum of value with other value of same ID in difference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with `mysql` script.

I have 2 tables, I want to compare my `invoiceAmount` with `paymentAmount` in another table. The situation is: many payments can be for one invoice, I want to compare `invoiceAmount (table A)` with `paymentAmount (table B)`.

I already joined it with calculated `paymentAmount` of the same invoiceID, my problem is how to compare it(sum of `paymentAmount(table B)` with `invoiceAmount (table A)` of the same invoiceID from both tables for all row)? really need your helps guys..

my script is:

```
SELECT invoice.InvoiceID, invoice.InvoiceAmount, pays.InvoiceID, sum(pays.PaymentAmount) as pays, invoice.InvoiceDate 
FROM `payment from customer` as pays
JOIN invoice ON(pays.InvoiceID=invoice.InvoiceID)
WHERE pays.InvoiceID in (
    SELECT InvoiceID 
    FROM `payment from customer`
    GROUP BY InvoiceID
    HAVING count(*) > 1)
GROUP BY pays.InvoiceID
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: `from 'payment from customer' as pays` --> it's generally not a good idea to use spaces in your table names, especially if the table name contains the word 'FROM'.

Comment: golimar: i want to find sum(pays.PaymentAmount) > invoice.InvoiceAmount..

Comment: Still stuck? Consider providing a sqlfiddle, together WITH your desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select invoice.InvoiceID, 
             invoice.InvoiceAmount, 
             pays.InvoiceID, 
             pays.PaymentAmount as pays, 
             invoice.InvoiceDate ,
             (select sum(a.PaymentAmount) 
                from `payment from customer` a 
               where a.InvoiceID = invoice.InvoiceID) totalPays
        from `payment from customer` as pays JOIN invoice 
          ON (pays.InvoiceID=invoice.InvoiceID) ) temp
where InvoiceDate > totalPays
```

Comment: i mean, where i add this code..
   WHERE totalPays>invoice.InvoiceAmount, i always get this error..
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'totalPays' in 'where clause'.
i want to select 'totalPays'>invoice.InvoiceAmount, pls help..

Comment: put it in having clause. ie. ifter group by clause `HAVING totalPays>invoice.InvoiceAmount`

Comment: or you can enclose it in inline view

Comment: select invoice.InvoiceID, 
         invoice.InvoiceAmount, 
         pays.InvoiceID, 
         pays.PaymentAmount as pays, 
         invoice.InvoiceDate ,
         (select sum(a.PaymentAmount) 
            from `payment from customer` a 
           where a.InvoiceID = invoice.InvoiceID) totalPays
    from `payment from customer` as pays JOIN invoice 
      ON (pays.InvoiceID=invoice.InvoiceID)
GROUP by pays.InvoiceID;

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to your result table in which you calculate the sum that still has to be paid.

For example, should you want a list of invoices that still have a balance to pay:

```
  SELECT invoice.InvoiceID,
         invoice.InvoiceAmount,
         pays.InvoiceID,
         sum(pays.PaymentAmount) AS pays,
         sum(pays.PaymentAmount) - invoice.InvoiceAmount AS StillToPay
         invoice.InvoiceDate
    FROM `payment from customer` AS pays
         JOIN invoice ON pays.InvoiceID = invoice.InvoiceID
   WHERE pays.InvoiceID IN (   SELECT InvoiceID FROM `payment from customer`
                             GROUP BY InvoiceID
                               HAVING count(*) > 1 )
     AND StillToPay > 0
GROUP BY pays.InvoiceID
```

**Untested query!**

Comment: Marty McVry: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'StillToPay' in 'where clause'